# Combine lists having a specific merge order in a pythonic way?

Tags: python

I would like to construct list `x` from two lists `y` and `z`. I want all elements from `y` be placed where `ypos` elements point. For example:

```
y = [11, 13, 15]
z = [12, 14]
ypos = [1, 3, 5]
```

So, `x` must be `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`

Another example:

```
y = [77]
z = [35, 58, 74]
ypos = [3]
```

So, `x` must be `[35, 58, 77, 74]`

I've written function that does what I want but it looks ugly:

```
def func(y, z, ypos):
    x = [0] * (len(y) + len(z))
    zpos = list(range(len(y) + len(z)))
    for i, j in zip(y, ypos):
        x[j-1] = i
        zpos.remove(j-1)
    for i, j in zip(z, zpos):
        x[j] = i
    return x
```

How to write it in pythonic way?

Comment: I guess you need to post this question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @TigranSaluev Changing the name would make it ok, so not really I think.

Comment: @martineau, sorry, fixed

Comment: @scharette He has working code and is looking to improve it's style to closer fit a language. That isn't within the scope of SO.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If the lists are very long, repeatedly calling `insert` [might not be very efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27073672/1639625). Alternatively, you could create two `iterators` from the lists and construct a list by getting the `next` element from either of the iterators depending on whether the current index is in `ypos` (or a `set` thereof):

```
>>> ity = iter(y)
>>> itz = iter(z)
>>> syp = set(ypos)
>>> [next(ity if i+1 in syp else itz) for i in range(len(y)+len(z))]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Note: this will insert the elements from `y` in the order they appear in `y` itself, i.e. the first element of `y` is inserted at the *lowest* index in `ypos`, not necessarily at the *first* index in `ypos`. If the elements of `y` should be inserted at the index of the *corresponding element* of `ypos`, then either `ypos` has to be in ascending order (i.e. the first index of `ypos` is also the lowest), or the iterator of `y` has to be sorted by the same order as the indices in `ypos` (afterwards, `ypos` itself does not have to be sorted, as we are turning it into a `set` anyway).

```
>>> ypos = [5,3,1]   # y and z being same as above
>>> ity = iter(e for i, e in sorted(zip(ypos, y)))
>>> [next(ity if i+1 in syp else itz) for i in range(len(y)+len(z))]
[15, 12, 13, 14, 11]
```

Comment: Excellent approach. It mimics the way you'd distribute cards from two decks.

Comment: Can equivalently make `i+1` just `i` and change range to `range(1, len(y)+len(z)+1)` as it would remove `n - 1` `i+1` operations, but that's really just a nitpick micro optimization.

Comment: It may be obvious, but one should ensure that `len(y) == len(ypos)` before running the list comprehension.

Comment: It's not clear at first, but you basically sort `ypos` again since you iterate with an increasing `i`. You can try with `f([15, 13, 11], [12, 14], [5, 3, 1])`. It returns `[15, 12, 13, 14, 11]`, as if `ypos` was `[1, 3, 5]`.

Comment: @EricDuminil Ah, now I get what you mean. But `ypos` does not have to be sorted, instead my approach ignores any order of `ypos` and just adds the elements from `y` in the order they have, not at the "corresponding" position in `ypos`. Interesting point.

Comment: @tobias_k: Indeed. `ypos` can be written in any order you want but `y` should be written in the same order as a sorted `ypos`. :)

Comment: @EricDuminil Interesting discussion. It inspired me to add an answer that uses an alternative approach to preserving the corresponding positions.

Answer (score 12):

You should use `list.insert`, this is what it was made for!

```
def func(y, z, ypos):
    x = z[:]
    for pos, val in zip(ypos, y):
        x.insert(pos-1, val)
    return x
```

and a test:

```
>>> func([11, 13, 15], [12, 14], [1,3,5])
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: since the question was about constructing a new list, you should copy `z` so it is not modifying the original list.

Comment: This assumes the indexes will be in order

Comment: @C.Feenstra The question assumes they are. It is impossible to know how they should be ordered (i.e. do we order just the `indexes`, or do we `zip` them, then order) so I decided this wasn't necessary. However if the OP explicitly states their position on this aspect then by all means, I will update the answer **:)**

Comment: Yes, the order in `x` must hold like in your answer

Comment: If `ypos` might not be ordered, you could just use `sorted(ypos)` i.e. `for pos, val in zip(sorted(ypos), y):`

Comment: @ArthurTacca: You cannot sort `ypos` without also reorganizing `y`.

Comment: BTW, this approach is fine with list of hundreds of elements. With larger lists, it becomes really slow.

Comment: @EricDuminil My mistake, it should be `sorted(zip(ypos, y))`. And your second comment is sort of my point; for a few hundred elements it's fine; often with this sort of question, that's the type of number involved.

Answer (score 8):

With large lists, it might be a good idea to work with [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).

## Algorithm

- create a new array as large as `y + z`
- calculate coordinates for `z` values
- assign `y` values to `x` at `ypos`
- assign `z` values to `x` at `zpos`

The complexity should be `O(n)`, with `n` being the total number of values.

```
import numpy as np

def distribute_values(y_list, z_list, y_pos):
    y = np.array(y_list)
    z = np.array(z_list)
    n = y.size + z.size
    x = np.empty(n, np.int)
    y_indices = np.array(y_pos) - 1
    z_indices = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(n), y_indices, assume_unique=True)
    x[y_indices] = y
    x[z_indices] = z
    return x

print(distribute_values([11, 13, 15], [12, 14], [1, 3, 5]))
# [11 12 13 14 15]
print(distribute_values([77], [35, 58, 74], [3]))
# [35 58 77 74]
```

As a bonus, it also works fine when `ypos` isn't sorted:

```
print(distribute_values([15, 13, 11], [12, 14], [5, 3, 1]))
# [11 12 13 14 15]
print(distribute_values([15, 11, 13], [12, 14], [5, 1, 3]))
# [11 12 13 14 15]
```

## Performance

With `n` set to 1 million, this approach is a bit faster than [@tobias_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) and 500 times faster than [@Joe_Iddon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47443369/6419007).

The lists were created this way:

```
from random import random, randint
N = 1000000
ypos = [i+1 for i in range(N) if random()<0.4]
y = [randint(0, 10000) for _ in ypos]
z = [randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(N - len(y))
```

Here are the results with [`%timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) and IPython:

```
%timeit eric(y, z, ypos)
131 ms ± 1.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit tobias(y, z, ypos)
224 ms ± 977 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit joe(y,z, ypos)
54 s ± 1.48 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Nice timing analysis, but I'd say mine only takes 1.5 times longer (in fact, I got 135 and 179 ms respectively). :-P Surprised Joe's isn't slower, though, I'd expect it to be quadratic.

Comment: @tobias_k: Yes, it depends on the system and underlying libraries. Factor 1.5 or 2 isn't much with such a large list. I was surprised by Joe
's answer with smaller lists. With `n=100`, it was actually a bit faster than yours for example.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `ypos` indices are sorted, here is another solution using iterators, though this one also supports `ypos` of unknown or infinite length:

```
import itertools

def func(y, ypos, z):
    y = iter(y)
    ypos = iter(ypos)
    z = iter(z)
    next_ypos = next(ypos, -1)
    for i in itertools.count(start=1):
        if i == next_ypos:
            yield next(y)
            next_ypos = next(ypos, -1)
        else:
            yield next(z)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the elements in `ypos` to be placed at the `x` index where each element's index in `ypos` should correspond with the same `y` index's element:

1. Initialize `x` to the required size using all null values.
2. Iterate through the zipped `y` and `ypos` elements to fill in each corresponding `y` element into `x`.
3. Iterate through `x` and replace each remaining null value with `z` values where each replacement will choose from `z` in increasing
   order.

```
y = [11, 13, 15]
z = [12, 14]
ypos = [1, 5, 3]

x = [None] * (len(y) + len(z))
for x_ypos, y_elem in zip(ypos, y):
    x[x_ypos - 1] = y_elem

z_iter = iter(z)
x = [next(z_iter) if i is None else i for i in x]
# x -> [11, 12, 15, 14, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pythonic way

```
y = [11, 13, 15]
z = [12, 14]
ypos = [1, 3, 5]

x = z[:]

for c, n in enumerate(ypos):
    x.insert(n - 1, y[c])

print(x)
```

output

> [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

## In a function

```
def func(y, ypos, z):
    x = z[:]
    for c,n in enumerate(ypos):
        x.insert(n-1,y[c])
    return x

print(func([11,13,15],[1,2,3],[12,14]))
```

outoput

> [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

## Using zip

```
y, z, ypos = [11, 13, 15], [12, 14], [1, 3, 5]

for i, c in zip(ypos, y):
    z.insert(i - 1, c)

print(z)
```

[out:]

```
> [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```